# Take a Cells Comment and store it into a string varable

Tags: excel, vba, string, type-conversion

what I am trying to achieve is my work has cell data that is defined in the cell and the description is stored in a comment. is it possible to remove and store this into a string or something similar to allow me to paste it into a printable format, on a generated printout page.

```
dim myval as string
dim cmt as comment

Sheets("DData").Activate
set cmt = [H4].comment
myval = cmt.comment
Sheets("Generated Profile").Activate
cells(24,7) = myval
```

This is my form:
[image: Picture of Form]

And this is my workbook data page:
[image: Picture of my workbook data page]

any help would be greatly appreciated, this is my first post here so if am improperly posting please redirect me.

thanks.

Comment: Looks like it is in `myval`, which is a string. Can you explain where the problem is exactly?

Comment: thanks for the response, what happens when i reach the line where myval is trying to grab cmt.text. i actually just found the solution i was calling cmt.comment not cmt.text when writing to myval.

Comment: A lot going on between...`Sheets("Generated Profile").Cells(24,7) = Sheets("DData").Cells(4,8).Comment.Text`.  No need to Activate twice or set intermediary values.

Comment: Darrell H, thanks didn't know that was a viable option pulling specifically without changing the page.

Comment: In general it's a good idea to [avoid using activate and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that i fat fingered the entry of the code when

```
myval = cmt.comment
```

should be

```
myval = cmt.text
```

although it should be mentioned that Darrell h (quoted below gave a better solution)
here is their code.

```
Sheets("Generated Profile").Cells(24,7) = Sheets("DData").Cells(4,8).Comment.Text
```

"A lot going on between...Sheets("Generated Profile").Cells(24,7) = Sheets("DData").Cells(4,8).Comment.Text. No need to Activate twice or set intermediary values." – Darrell H

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim comment As String
comment = Range("A1").comment.Text
```

Replacing the cell above with whatever cell you want.